# how to search all the tables of the database using php mysqli and display the answer

Tags: php, mysql

i am just beginning to learn **mysqli** and **php** ...so i am a novice.
i am trying to build a site for babynames.

i have a database of **babynames** in **phpmyadmin**. having tables **country1**, **country2**, **country3**....and so on. all the tables have the same columns **id**, **name**, **meaning**, **gender** and **alphabet**.

i print the names table using the following code using PHP and MYSQLI

```
$sql1="SELECT id,name, meaning, alpha, gender FROM $country WHERE gender='$gender' AND alpha='$alpha' $limit";
    $query=mysqli_query($con,$sql1);    

while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){

        echo "<td><a href='meaning-of.php?name=$rows[name]'>".$rows['name']."</a></td>";
        echo "<td>".$rows['meaning']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$rows['gender']."</td></tr>";
        }
```

the **name** column is linked to `meaning-of.php?name=$rows[name]`

Now i want a code in PHP and MYSQLI to search all the tables(say 100 tables) of the database "babynames" for a particular **name** and display the same **name** and  **meaning** please. 
if the **name** exists more than once in the tables than all the names should be displayed along with their respective meanings please.

how do i search all the tables for a particular name and display using PHP and MYSQLI please.

i want to search the database by  passing only the **name** variable into the address bar like this **http://localhost/meaning-of.php?name=John** or **http://localhost/meaning-of.php?name=samson** and find the meaning by searching all the tables of the database based on only the name please.like if the name is set than getting the name by  **$name=$_GET["name"];** and then search the whole database tables and display the **meaning**

is there a code something like this

```
SELECT *(all columns) FROM * (all the tables or the database name or all the databases) WHERE name=$name;
```

Please help. Thank You in advance please.

Comment: maybe tidying up your db might help. one table that has your list of `countries` and a `unique key` value. a table of `names` with a `unique key` value, then create another table `uses` that has `names.key` and `countries.key` in it. some names probably sit in more than one country so would appear like `1,2` and `1,3`. querying all names would be easier, querying a specific countries names would be easy too.

Comment: Read my comment under Your Common Sense his answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep all your data in a **single table**, adding a field `country` to distinguish the country.

This is the only proper answer to this question.

Comment: Your Common Sense is 100% right. Restructure your database. Make a table called `Countries` and give it an `ID` column with a `primary key` (+ `auto increment` optional). Then in `Babynames` a column called `CountryID` or whatever suits you. Then 'connect' the `Countries` table to the `Babynames` table with the `primary key` of the `Countries` table. Or as (less preferred) option you can just put the country name in the `CountryID` column (offcourse rename it to `Country` ;-) )

Comment: ya it is a good way to do that. but it would make the table very big. i am planning for more than 100,000 names. i feel that having such a big table would take more time for searching and retrieving the data. that is why i want to have separate tables.

Comment: @rajendraprasad tables intended to be big. It's all right for a database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNION clause to get results from multiple select statements [mysql doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html)

```
(SELECT * FROM county1 WHERE name=$name)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM county2 WHERE name=$name);
```

You can query all table names from information_schema

```
SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_name LIKE "country%"
    AND table_schema = "<name_of_country_database>";
```

So the full solution would be something like this:

```
    $tables_sql = "SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name LIKE 'country%' AND table_schema = 'babynames'";
    $tables_query = mysqli_query($con,$tables_sql);

    $sql1 = '';
    while ($table = mysqli_fetch_array($tables_query)) {
        if ($sql1 != '') {
            $sql1 .= ' UNION ';
        }
        $sql1.= " (SELECT name, meaning FROM " . $table['table_name'] . " WHERE name='$name') ";
    }

    $query=mysqli_query($con,$sql1);
    while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$rows['name']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$rows['meaning']."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
```

Comment: thank u very much for the response. suppose say i have 100 tables ...the UNION code would become very big. i want to search the whole database all at once with a small straight forward code please.

Comment: I'm not aware you can do easy select from multiple tables at once by giving table wildcard. What you can do though, is to query table names from information_schema and then compose the UNION query in php.

Comment: i once again appreciate for your answer. i want to search the database by  passing only the **name** variable into the address bar like this **http://localhost/meaning-of.php?name=John** and find the meaning by searching all the tables of the database based on only the name please.

Comment: I fixed the queries, but overall logic remains the same.